# Nested Generics Registration using Unity configuration file

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an interface and implementation as follows:

```
public interface IDataProcessor<T, U>
    {
        U Process(T data);
    }

public sealed class CustomDataProc: IDataProcessor<List<string>, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>
    {
          ...
    }
```

When I register this implementation using conventional style as below, everything resolves fine and okay.

```
container.RegisterType<IDataProcessor<List<string>, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>, CustomDataProc>();
```

Now, when using XML as below registration (i.e. call to container.LoadConfiguration(section)) passes but when resolving the root object it fails.

```
<typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias ="Dictionary" type ="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2, mscorlib" />
    <typeAlias alias ="List" type ="System.Collections.Generic.List`1, mscorlib" />
...
</typeAliases>
<container>
<register type="IDataProcessor[List[string], Dictionary[string, Dictionary[string, List[string]]]]" mapTo="CustomDataProc"/>
...
</container>
```

This fails with error

```
"Resolution of the dependency failed, type = ... 
while resolving.\r\nException is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, 
IDataProcessor`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]]], 
is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

I think it has something to do with nested generics since one of my other type mapping with single generic worked fine.

Any idea how this can be resolved sucessfully ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
<typeAliases>
  <typeAlias alias="IDataProcessor" type="StackOverflow_30583255.IDataProcessor`2, StackOverflow_30583255" />
  <typeAlias alias="CustomDataProc" type="StackOverflow_30583255.CustomDataProc, StackOverflow_30583255" />
</typeAliases>
<container>
  <register type="IDataProcessor`2[List[string],Dictionary[string,Dictionary[string,List[string]]]]" mapTo="CustomDataProc" />
</container>
```

Comment: Thanks looks like in registering also you need a back tick (`). Works now !